# What is the workflow for product keys activation in Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB and WICD

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation

I have hosts that will be running Win10 Enterprise LTSB 1607 and I have purchased keys for them from a well-known VLA-connected vendor. The vendor is helpful but as confused as I by the new Win10 system.

I want to use the WICD tools from the ADK  ( or if required the other tools in ADK) to produce 'golden-master' disk images which we will copy onto each host. We could add the key to each host after disk-copying or use the key inside the WICD process, or manually add the key to the golden master before using it.

I have been given two keys, one for "development" and one for use on the hosts.

So far I have not been able to produce a system image that does not ask to be activated. When I try to manually activate, the keys I was given are refused.

**What is the correct workflow for install.wim -> WICD -> bootable USB -> install on reference system-> tweak -> disk image -> install on hosts?**

Comment: "When I try to manually activate, the keys I was given are refused."  - Have you called the Microsoft Activation Center?  You are trying to activate your installations against a KMS right?

Comment: No, not KMS. I have a key for x number of units that I bought. I have the ADK which includes WICD, and I have a generic wim image for Enterprise ltsb

Comment: Enterprise is activated through KMS.

Comment: so is this a MAK?

Comment: No, not MAK, not KMS. We are shipping off-the-shelf hardware with Win10 Enterprise LTSB as customized by us, shipping to customers. Similar to what we do with Win7 embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workflow for Win10 Enterprise LTSB and WICD:

( Its a good guess but untested, that this will work for all the versions of embedded Win10)

Go to a vendor ( we used Arrow for example) and they will sell you a block of licenses at pretty much any scale 1-1mill. This entails getting you a key and an email address at Microsoft. You email the MS address with the VLA of the vendor ( ask your vendor about this part) and when I did I got a Fedex with CDs and printed documentation including two product keys.

I figured out by elimination which of the two keys to use ( ask your vendor for help).

Install the toolchains from the CDs. I used Win10, but they might work on Win7. I chose to use the WICD app ( more on this later). Download a wim file from MS for your flavor ( LTSB, IOT, whatever). Open a project in WICD using the wim file. Modify your project as needed ( huge number of confusing settings). Find "product key" and put the key you got from the MS email in the field.  Save and do a "Clean Install" to a bootable USB stick. Use this stick to install on a target system. Boot and continue to modify until satisfied. This system can be cloned, so its your Golden Master.

This workflow produced clones that were activated and did not show the watermark calling for activation. The licenses are tracked with tiny stickers you put on the systems that have been imaged. You can do whatever you want for R&D purposes, but systems you sell are supposed to have the sticker. I don't actually know if there is any call-home mechanism to count your licenses, but I was assured that MS wouldn't create a popup or other message on the endpoints no matter what.

More: I was told afterward that WICD might not be the preferred tool, and indeed I found it quite unreliable. A number of parameters have multiple overlapped fields, this may cause issues, it certainly is confusing.